# Spring-boot how to accept JWTs without an issuer field?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt

If a JWT is missing an issuer field, I'd like to fallback to a jwk-uri or jwk-key-set, what would I need to override in Spring oauth2 libs because failing on missing issuer is a Spring default behavior.

An alternative would be to detect missing issuer field and inject that field with a string such as `emptyIssuer`... then I can define the appropriate issuer in application properties.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot, define  just `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri` property (and not `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri`).

The JWK set is enough for the decoder to validate JWT signature.

If `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri` is set, then

- JWT decoder is configured to check `iss` claim against the value in the conf
- boot does its best to infer `jwk-set-uri` from the `issuer-uri` (and succeeds when the authorization-server is OIDC complient)

Comment: This would work if the JWT contains empty issuer `iss: `.. But what if the `iss` isn't there to begin with?

Comment: I meant do not define it (instead of define it empty). Editing the answer to be more precise.